# MS Access Table: Correct for non leading zeroes in Zip_CD Field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm back to Access after an extended leave and am running into some difficulty.  I have a table that includes a Zip Code field.  Some of the Zip codes that are supplied are 5 digits (52186) and some are the 10 digit type with trailing neighborhood code (77005-1568).  However the leading zeroes have not been preserved and I need to reinsert them.  For instance (04074) shows up at (4070).  The 9 digit zip codes however have included the leading zeroes.  I need a way to add the leading zeroes to the 5 digit zip codes.  I cannot use a trick like converting to a number and then formatting to "00000" because that creates havoc with the 9 digit zips.  Also since  I've been absent from Access for so long I'm not sure if I should do this with a function, a query, some type of VBA RecordSet or what.  I can't recall the best way to approach.  Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

-Charlie

Comment: update table set [zip] = right("00000'&[zip], 5) where int([zip])<10000

Comment: I think you need Val([zip]) instead of Int([zip])

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
TrueZip = IIf(IsNumeric([Zip]), Format([Zip], "00000"), Right("00" & [Zip], 10))
```

In a query, it would (in the GUI) be:

```
TrueZip: IIf(IsNumeric([Zip]),Format([Zip],"00000"),Right("00" & [Zip],10))
```

As SQL, it would go like this:

```
Select 
    *,
    IIf(IsNumeric([Zip]),Format([Zip],"00000"),Right("00" & [Zip],10)) As TrueZip
From
    YourTable
```

Comment: Would this be in a query or in a formula?  I tried it in a query and I couldn't get it to work but then again I am extremely rusty with Access

Comment: See extended answer, please.